# Label (Category) for Humidity Controller

Tags: smart-home

This post is *not* a request for a product recommendation. The request is for the labels to improve the ability search and find the correct product.

Goal: *remotely* controlling (limiting) humidity in remote Florida buildings, which are outfitted with AC / heatpumps.

Context: The existing controller is 1990's technology (mercury switch thermometer).  Wi-Fi has been installed in anticipation of replacing with networked controllers.  Although my CT80 RadioThermostat is able to produce excellent temperature visualization it does not record and visualize humidity.

[image: Runtime per hour graph of thermostat]

Ideally, there would be second plot on the same graph that plots the relative humidity.

## QUESTIONS

What is the label (keywords) to search for:

- a controller (keyword = thermostat is too limiting?) that
- records  humidity (key word = humidity? )?
- plots / visualizes humidity (keyword = ???) in manner similar to above?

Again, this is *not* a request for product recommendation.

Comment: `a controller (keyword = thermostat is too limiting?) that` .... the thermostat is not a controller in this context .... it is a temperature sensor ......... you are looking for a humidity sensor

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but the plot in the included picture looks like it was not generated by the CT80 RadioThermostat  ...... it looks like it was generated by program on a computer or on a smartphone ..... the program probably obtained a log of temperature readings from the thermostat

Comment: @jstola  Yes, the radiothermostat server collects data from the thermostat and plots graphs as shown above.  The thermostat measures and forwards data for visualization, which is performed on a webserver.